# Foreach loop Json array

Tags: php, json

I am learning to work with Json at the moment, I have figured out how to display data for Name and Craft in space in the moment. 
I cannot figure out how to display number of people.

Is not correct, I am receiving error

```
foreach ($json_data['number'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Also does not work

```
foreach($json_data as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key['number'];
}
```

```
// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json');
//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Craft</th> 
    </tr>
<?php foreach($json_data['people'] as $key=>$value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['craft']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I want to display number of people in the space by using foreach loop

Comment: Try using print_r($json_data, true), that will dump the content of the variable and give you some insight into the possible problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```php
<?php
// Read JSON file
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json');

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
$peopleCount = 0;
?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Craft</th>
        </tr>
    <?php foreach($json_data['people'] as $key=>$value):
        $peopleCount++;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['craft']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php
echo "Total People count: ". $peopleCount;
```

explanation:

`$peopleCount` variable is holding the number of people.
At first, its values is `0`.

When iterating over the array the `$peopleCount`'s value is incrementing by `1` (`$peopleCount++;` is equal to `$peopleCount = $peopleCount +1;`)

PS:
Your code had missing PHP closing tag at line number 8. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` is used to loop through an `array`. In your JSON output `number` is not returned as an array, so you do not need to use `foreach` loop for displaying number. You can just display the Number using following code:

```
<?php echo $json_data['number']; ?>
```

Comment: it is exactly what I use to display the number, but I thought that it will be better to display by foreach. Thank you for :-)